# Multiple solutions from IK solver?

Tags: ros, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to obtain multiple IK solutions for all the joints of an arm from the IK Solver (pr2_right_arm_kinematics/get_ik) for one specific pose of a link (i.e. r_wrist_roll_link)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10319/multiple-solutions-from-ik-solver?/) by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 207 on 2011-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is possible. You can call the service multiple times with a different state in the ik_seed_state each time and it should give you different solutions.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2